# How to read a pointer to a pointer C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

Could you advise me the best way to read a pointer? I know that a pointer should be read from right to left and that the `const` qualifier should be on the right. My problem and when it comes to reading a pointer to a pointer, for example:

```
int i = 10; 
int const *const p = &i; 
int const *const *p2 = &p; //how should I read this ?
```

Should I read `p2` has a pointer to a `const` pointer to `const`?

Why does `p2` become a `const` pointer if I just specify that it points to a `const` pointer?

Comment: I got a bit confused reading this.. I thought you were asking how to "read" P2 as in how to de-reference it & print it.. then I realised you meant read it "mentally". So for anyone else as slow as me, I hope this clarifies OP's question.

Comment: "I know that a pointer should be read from right" - that's right, so what's the problem? Reading from right to left, "`p2` is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant `int`". As for your last question: it doesn't become `const`, it just points to something `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, p2 is a pointer to a const pointer to a const int. The pointer itself isn't const, but what it points at is. It's that way because that's how you declared it.

In case it wasn't clear: a pointer to const means you can't write to something via that pointer.

A const pointer means the pointer itself can't be change--you have to initialize it with the address of one object and can never modify the pointer to refer to any other object. With `p2` as you've declared it, you can read by not write the value it points *at*, but you can modify the pointer itself so it refers to some other object if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

"p2 is a pointer to a constant pointer to a constant int."

"p is a constant pointer to a constant int."

Note "constant pointer" vs. "pointer to a constant."  The former is a pointer which cannot point to anything else; the latter is a pointer which may be changed to point elsewhere, but whatever it points to, it cannot be used to change.

Comment: "constant" is misleading--you can't change the value pointed at via that const pointer, but it could still change (e.g., by being written to directly instead of via that pointer).

Comment: That's why I said "it (the pointer) cannot be used to change" "whatever it points to."  Yes, something else could change it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, basically you can reassign another value to `p2`: it's a pointer  to a `const` pointer to `const` `int`.

Answer (score 0):

p2 is not a constant pointer. It will become constant if you specify it like this:

```
int const *const *const p2 = &p;
```

Now, it's const pointer to a const pointer to a const int.

In your original declaration, it's a pointer to a const pointer to a const int.